# Как можно сдвинуть кнопку влево?

Tags: html, css

https://unbrokenteam.ru/

Применил к кнопкам "Подробнее" и "Отправить заявку"

```html
<button class="noTableBorder button">Отправить</button>
```

Все равно они не сместились влево.

В style.css добавил:

```css
.noTableBorder button {
  left: 0; 
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: none;
  display:  block;
}
```

Вот файлы:
[index.html](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7kpT/5SKqunjYU)
[style.css](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/a6km/Q9WqB6HNG)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что вы хотите? У вас left и margin-left 0. За счёт чего она должна была сместиться?

Comment: Я ставил вот так: .noTableBorder button {
    left: 75%; 
    margin-left: 75%;
    transform: none;
    display:  block;
    } и все равно кнопки не смещаются влево

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В css у вас классы из-за отвутствия запятой не применяются. Код ниже применит стили для всех кнопок и всего, что с классом `.noTableBorder`

```css
.noTableBorder, button { 
  left: 75%; 
  margin-left: 75%;
  transform: none; 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<button class="noTableBorder button">Отправить</button>
```

Так, если вы хотели сделать для всех кнопок с классом `noTableBorder`

```css
 button.noTableBorder {
  left: 75%; 
  margin-left: 75%;
  transform: none;
  display:  block;
}
```

```html
<button class="noTableBorder button">Отправить</button>
```

То есть запятая это как **или**, а слитное написание как **и**

А если вы хотели использовать `.noTableBorder button` как один класс, то с пробелом нельзя, используйте `.noTableBorder-button`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!