# Не работает CSS-класс. Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, html, css

После введение класса  ничего не работает, в чём ошибка понять не могу

```
.product-item_wrapper .product-item_not-available .product-item_price{
    display: none;
}

.product-item_notify-text{
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.product-item_wrapper .product-item_not-available .product-item_notify-text{
    display: block;
}

.product-item_wrapper .product-item_not-available .product-item_basket{
    display: none;
}
```

Вот HTML-разметка:

```
<section class="products">
<div class="container">
  <div class="products_inner">
    <h3 class="product_title">
      Популярные товары
    </h3>
    <div class="tabs-wrapper">
      <div class="tabs products_tabs">
        <a class="tab  products_tab tab--active" href="#product-tab-1">Запчасти</a>
        <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-2">Моторы</a>
        <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-3">Шины</a>
        <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-4">Электроника</a>
        <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-5">Инструменты</a>
        <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-6">Аксессуары</a>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs-content products_content tabs-content--active">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-slider_item">
              <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                  <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                    Посмотреть товар
                  </p>
                  <button class="product-item_favorite">
                  </button>
                  <button class="product-item_basket">
                    <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                  <h4 class="product-item_title">
                    Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                  </h4>
                  <p class="price product-item_price">
               9800$
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-slider_item">
                <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                  <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                    <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                      Посмотреть товар
                    </p>
                    <button class="product-item_favorite">
                    </button>
                    <button class="product-item_basket">
                      <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                    <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4 class="product-item_title">
                      Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                    </h4>
                    <p class="price product-item_price">
                 9800$
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-slider_item">
              <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                  <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                    Посмотреть товар
                  </p>
                  <button class="product-item_favorite">
                  </button>
                  <button class="product-item_basket">
                    <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                  <h4 class="product-item_title">
                    Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                  </h4>
                  <p class="price product-item_price">
               9800$
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-slider_item">
                <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                  <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                    <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                      Посмотреть товар
                    </p>
                    <button class="product-item_favorite">
                    </button>
                    <button class="product-item_basket">
                      <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                    <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4 class="product-item_title">
                      Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                    </h4>
                    <p class="price product-item_price">
                 9800$
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: а html разметку мы должны угадать?

Comment: и что значит "После введение класса" ?

Comment: "ничего не работает" --- отличное описание проблемы! Де-таль-но-е!

Comment: Вот  html-разметка. В каждом интернет магазине вставляют ставляют специальный класс на время,пока товар в продаже не появится. У меня этот класс не работает

Comment: что значит "не работает" ?

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что проблема здесь такая же как и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407402/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE)

```css
.product-item_wrapper, .product-item_not-available, .product-item_price{
    display: none;
}

.product-item_notify-text{
    display: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.product-item_wrapper, .product-item_not-available, .product-item_notify-text{
    display: block;
}

.product-item_wrapper, .product-item_not-available, .product-item_basket{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="products">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="products_inner">
        <h3 class="product_title">
          Популярные товары
        </h3>
        <div class="tabs-wrapper">
          <div class="tabs products_tabs">
            <a class="tab  products_tab tab--active" href="#product-tab-1">Запчасти</a>
          <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-2">Моторы</a>
          <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-3">Шины</a>
          <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-4">Электроника</a>
          <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-5">Инструменты</a>
          <a class="tab  products_tab" href="#product-tab-6">Аксессуары</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-content products_content tabs-content--active">
          <div class="product-slider">
            <div class="product-slider_item">
              <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                  <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                    Посмотреть товар
                  </p>
                  <button class="product-item_favorite">
                  </button>
                  <button class="product-item_basket">
                    <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                  <h4 class="product-item_title">
                    Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                  </h4>
                  <p class="price product-item_price">
               9800$
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-slider_item">
              <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                  <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                    Посмотреть товар
                  </p>
                  <button class="product-item_favorite">
                  </button>
                  <button class="product-item_basket">
                    <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                  <h4 class="product-item_title">
                    Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                  </h4>
                  <p class="price product-item_price">
               9800$
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-slider_item">
                <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                  <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                    <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                      Посмотреть товар
                    </p>
                    <button class="product-item_favorite">
                    </button>
                    <button class="product-item_basket">
                      <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                    <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4 class="product-item_title">
                      Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                    </h4>
                    <p class="price product-item_price">
                 9800$
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-slider_item">
                  <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                    <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                      <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                        Посмотреть товар
                      </p>
                      <button class="product-item_favorite">
                      </button>
                      <button class="product-item_basket">
                        <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                      </button>
                      <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                      <h4 class="product-item_title">
                        Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                      </h4>
                      <p class="price product-item_price">
                   9800$
                      </p>
                    </a>
                  </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
       <div class="tabs-content products_content">
        <div class="product-slider">
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product-slider_item">
            <div class="product-item_wrapper">
              <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                  Посмотреть товар
                </p>
                <button class="product-item_favorite">
                </button>
                <button class="product-item_basket">
                  <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                </button>
                <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                <h4 class="product-item_title">
                  Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                </h4>
                <p class="price product-item_price">
             9800$
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-slider_item">
              <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                  <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                    Посмотреть товар
                  </p>
                  <button class="product-item_favorite">
                  </button>
                  <button class="product-item_basket">
                    <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                  <h4 class="product-item_title">
                    Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                  </h4>
                  <p class="price product-item_price">
               9800$
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-slider_item">
                <div class="product-item_wrapper">
                  <a class="product-item product-item--sale" href="#">
                    <p class="product-item_hover-text">
                      Посмотреть товар
                    </p>
                    <button class="product-item_favorite">
                    </button>
                    <button class="product-item_basket">
                      <img src="images/basket-white.svg" alt="">
                    </button>
                    <img class="product-item_img" src="images/content/product-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4 class="product-item_title">
                      Водонепронецаемый рюкзак
                    </h4>
                    <p class="price product-item_price">
                 9800$
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
           <div class="tabs-content products_content "></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```